# side by side subfigures alignment problem

Tags: subfloats

I am new in latex writing. I am have problem with figures alignment. I am trying to put six figures on single page side by side. but the last figure is bit right shifted. I am no getting what could be the reason behind this. Please help me out to fix this problem. Thank you. Here is my code,

```
\begin{figure}[h]
            \begin{subfigure}[h]{7cm}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{images/er1.pdf}
                \caption{PE}
                \label{snr_a}
            \end{subfigure}             
            \begin{subfigure}[h]{7cm}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{images/sb.pdf}
                \caption{Pn}
                \label{snr_b}   
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[h]{7cm}   
                \centering      
                \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{images/s5.pdf}
                \caption{Pl}
                \label{snr_c}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[h]{7cm}   
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{images/s0.pdf}
                \caption{Pc}
                \label{snr_d}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[h]{7cm}   
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{images/s5.pdf}
                \caption{Pd}
                \label{snr_e}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[h]{7cm}   
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{images/s9.pdf}
                \caption{Pb}
                \label{snr_f}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{abcdef}
            \label{os}
        \end{figure}
```

Comment: Since we don't have your actual images we can try guessing: instead of `7cm` better use fractions of `\linewidth`, as in `0.5\linewidth`. Instead of controlling the scale for your images, control their width, as in `\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{...}`. Does this improve the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `[h]` option alone, use `[htp]`. Second, the `[h]` option doesn't make sense for `subfigure` (for which the same options as for `minipage` apply, that is, `[t]` or `[b]`, where the absence is equivalent to `[c]`).

It's also better to specify the width of figures, rather than a scale factor. In order to be independent of the actual text width, use a multiple of `\textwidth`, which is reset in a `subfigure` to the stated width.

The `figure` environment has a global `\centering`, which avoids the filling in the last line (it's the same as for normal paragraphs, otherwise, where the last line is filled). Two subfigures are placed side by side, with a width slightly less than half of the text width and `\hfill` between them. A blank line separates the rows. Adjust to suit your tastes.

I the example, for lack of your images, I also specify a height, but you shouldn't. Also the `demo` option is just for producing the example, don't use it yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for testing
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the 'demo' option in the production version
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{images/er1.pdf}
  \caption{PE}
  \label{snr_a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{images/sb.pdf}
  \caption{Pn}
  \label{snr_b}   
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}   
  \centering      
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{images/s5.pdf}
  \caption{Pl}
  \label{snr_c}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}   
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{images/s0.pdf}
  \caption{Pc}
  \label{snr_d}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}   
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{images/s5.pdf}
  \caption{Pd}
  \label{snr_e}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}   
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{images/s9.pdf}
  \caption{Pb}
  \label{snr_f}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{abcdef}
\label{os}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I have this error after using your given example code,

Comment: Option clash for package graphicx. \usepackage

Comment: @Aajiz As I said, you should remove the `demo` option.